# Finatra vs Akka-http performance as a plain http library

Tags: scala, web-services, akka, akka-http, finatra

I need to build REST API for my services and I am new to `Scala`. I have come to know of `finatra` and `akka-http`. After studying for a while, I am more inclined towards `finatra` as it offers `java-style` syntax and methodology for web services. However, `akka` has a very close knit relation to `scala` and learning `akka-http` at this point might help me in my `scala` journey.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by performance? You only mention it in the title but not on your question. You can find comparisons of different Scala web frameworks here: https://github.com/mfirry/web-frameworks-templates

Comment: i meant, i am to choose one of these libraries and i want to know which one is more performant in terms of requests/sec and horizontal scaling.

Comment: these guys https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r18&hw=ph&test=plaintext&l=zijunz-f have done some comparisons. as always, they should be taken with a grain of salt. hopefully they'll help you anyways.

Answer (score 2):

They are on very different levels, akka-http is mainly a http server / client with very raw implementation and finatra is framework with modules, dependency injection, you get an administration view and page, flags and configuration. Finatra is the way to go if you like to have a more functional library then have a look at Finch https://finagle.github.io/finch/